# Unit testing promises in js-data-angular models

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, jsdata, js-data-angular

We use `js-data` and `js-data-angular` in our project.

I have the following model:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('dash.models')
    .factory('Diagnosis', ['DS', function (DS) {
      function transform(resourcename, attrs, cb) {
        attrs.icd9codes.forEach(function (el) {
          delete el.add;
        });
        cb(null, attrs);
      }

      this.transform = transform;

      return DS.defineResource({
        name: 'diagnosis',
        idAttribute: 'id',
        endpoint: '/diagnosis',
        baseUrl: '/api',
        beforeCreate: transform,
        beforeUpdate: transform
      });
    }]);

}());
```

And the following call to said model:

```
    var startEditing = self.startEditing = function(parentScope, diagnosis) {
      Diagnosis.findAll({
        deep:true
      }, {
        endpoint: '/diagnosis/' + diagnosis.id
      }).then(function(d) {
        $scope.diagnosis = d;
        $scope.inScope = true;
      });
    };
```

In my unit test, I mock the call like this:

```
var diagDeferred = _$q_.defer();
    diagDeferred.resolve({
      'name': 'Breast',
      'categories': null,
      'id': '026c7cd0-14ef-4312-a8f1-2092107b0e50',
      'icd9codes': [{id: '1', code: '001', description: 'ICD9 Code'}]
    });

    spyOn(Diagnosis, 'findAll').and.returnValue(diagDeferred.promise);
```

And the actual call is mocked, what doesn't get executed (and I can't find any reliable information on how to get this done) is the function inside the `.then` of the `Diagnosis.findAll`

I know the code works, but I need to cover it with unit tests and I'm coming up dry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to call `$scope.digest()` in your test. Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/2apwxqyq/).

After you call `startEditing()`, you should call `$scope.$digest()` so that your mock `promise` is executed and you can get your data in `then` block. Hope it helps.

Comment: That totally worked! I thought that I had tried that in the past and it didn't work, but it works for me now. Thanks so much!